# Testing a CLI made with docopt, with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, docopt

There is a part of the code in the file `fastq_trimmer.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    usage = '''
    Fastq Trimmer CLI.

    Usage:
        fastq_trimmer.py trim <filePath> <trimFactor>

    '''

    args = docopt(usage)

    if args['trim']:
        commenceOperation(args)
    else:
        print(usage)
```

Im trying to write a unittest :

```
import fastq_trimmer
from docopt import docopt

doc = fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation(args)

class TestTrimmer(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_exceptions(self):
        args = docopt(doc, ["/home/eliran/Desktop/example.fastq", "5"])
        self.assertEqual(args["<filePath>"], "/home/eliran/Desktop/example.fastq")
        self.assertEqual(args["<trimFactor>"], "5")
```

basically im trying to control the args variable from the unittest file so I can 'inject' the CLI with the args i specify in the unittest file.

Comment: The easiest way is to separate those concerns, guard the parsing and usage of command line arguments behind `if __name__ == "__main__":` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/3001761) so you can import the function and call it with whatever you want.

Comment: It raises an error : ```AttributeError: module 'fastq_trimmer' has no attribute 'args'
```

Comment: ... *what* does? The code you've shown? Is `args` actually being assigned at the module level?

Comment: i've changed the code as you suggested in ```fastq_trimmer.py```, will edit the changes in the question

Comment: That's right, `args` is no longer defined at the module level when the file is imported. You can now `fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation(<whatever you want>)`.

Comment: changed to ```doc = fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation(args)```, another error is raised : ```NameError: name 'args' is not defined```

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but... *did* you define `args`, before trying to pass it as an argument?

Comment: isn't this line defining args  ```args = docopt(usage)``` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But is `doc = fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation(args)` actually being executed in the scope where `args = docopt(usage)` was executed (in fact, was `args = docopt(usage)` being executed at all)? Because if not, it's unclear why you think that would be relevant.

Comment: Well yeah you are right that's not what im trying to do.
Im simply trying to create a docopt object from the unittest file so i can send it to ```fastq_trimmer.py``` with ```fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation(docoptObj)```

Comment: `docopt` just creates a *dictionary*, so you can do `fastq_trimmer.commenceOperation({ ... })` to test your function with different inputs.